# Java. Hibernate. org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate.
Now working on the example from web.
I have a MySQL database that contains some tables, including table "profession". This table has two cols: profession_id(auto-increment) and profession_name.

In java project I have a 'Test' class, that contains several methods for table processing and 'main' method. 
Processing methods are:

```
private void addProfession(String name) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Profession r = new Profession();
    r.setProfessionName(name);
    session.save(r);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

private ArrayList<Profession> getProfessions() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    ArrayList<Profession> result = (ArrayList<Profession>) session
            .createQuery("from Profession order by professionName").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return result;
}

private void deleteProfessions(ArrayList<Profession> result) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    for (Profession p : result) {
        System.out.println("Delete: " + p.getProfessionId() + ": " + p.getProfessionName());
        session.delete(p);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

private void deleteEntity(Object object){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(object);
    session.flush();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

'main' method contains these operations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.addProfession("Profession_1");
    test.addProfession("Profession_2");
    test.addProfession("Profession_3");
    test.addProfession("Profession_4");
    test.addProfession("Profession_5");

    ArrayList<Profession> result = test.getProfessions();

    test.deleteEntity(result.get(0));
    test.deleteProfessions(result);
}
```

So, the problems is: when I run it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3197)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
at firstproject.Main.deleteProfessions(Main.java:33)
at firstproject.Main.main(Main.java:57)
```

After reading several topics about this theme at stackoverflow I learned, that this problem somehow is connected with ids. So I decided to comment this code:

```
test.deleteEntity(result.get(0));
```

After that everything worked fine.

So the question is:
How do I avoid this exception if i need: 
1. Delete one of the rows('cos this problem also occurs when I delete for example result.get(3) and so on).
2. Delete remaining rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting a particular `Profession` also remove that from the `ArrayList`. For example

```
    test.deleteEntity(result.get(0));
    result.remove(0);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Shame on me!:)
Thank you so much.
Upd: the second way(that I didn't notice in the example) is to update result list by adding this 
`result = test.getProfessions();` after `test.deleteEntity(result.get(0));`